# How do I set up and log into a vpn from my mac in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have an instance and s3 bucket in AWS (which I'm limiting to a range of IPs). I'm wanting to create a VPN and be able to authenticate myself while trying to log into that VPN to get to that instance.

To simplify, I'm trying to set up a dev environment for my site. I'm wanting to make sure I can limit access to that instance. I'm wanting to use a service to authenticate anybody wanting to get to that instance. Is there a way to do all of this in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at AWS Client VPN:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html

This allows you to create a managed VPN server in your VPC which you can connect to using any OpenVPN client.  You could then allow traffic from this vpn to your instance using security group rules.

Alternatively you can achieve the same effect using OpenVPN on an EC2 server, available from the marketplace:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00MI40CAE/ref=mkt_wir_openvpn_byol

Requires a bit more set up but works just fine, perfect if AWS Client VPN isn't available in your region yet.

Both these approaches ensure that your EC2 instance remains in a private subnet and is not accessible directly from the internet.  Also, the OpenVPN client for mac works just fine.